# Using SKTexture:withImageNamed in a for loop to load animations crashes after playing 30 + animation

Tags: ios8, sprite-kit, nsmutablearray, skaction, sktexture

My code below creates a Texture from an image name from file lookups in a plist like (Duck1_1,Duck1_2,Duck1_3,etc) it loops through them then adds them to a mutable array. The mutable array is then used to animate with the textures stored and played with an SKAction. This works fine for the animations until 30-40 are played then it crashes and says too many files open and it can't open the files anymore.  Any ideas on how to stop this from happening?
thanks

```
//loadPlistForAnimationWithNames function 

NSMutableArray *animationToReturn = [NSMutableArray array];

for(NSString *frameNumber in animationFrameNumbers) {
    NSString *frameName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@.png",animationFramePrefix,frameNumber];
    if(frameName!=nil)
        [animationToReturn addObject:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:frameName]];

}

SKAction *action=nil;
action=[SKAction animateWithTextures:animationToReturn timePerFrame:animationDelay resize:NO restore:NO];
SKAction *repeatAction=nil;
repeatAction = [SKAction repeatAction:action count:1];
[animationToReturn removeAllObjects];
action=nil;
animationFrameNumbers=nil;
return repeatAction;

//Call to loadPlistForAnimationWithNames and run animation
SKAction *action=[animalObject loadPlistForAnimationWithNames:@"duckAnim1" andClassName:NSStringFromClass([self class])];
SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Duck1_1"];
sprite.position=CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2);
sprite.size=self.frame.size;
[sprite setZPosition:3];
[self addChild:sprite];
[sprite runAction:action];
```

Here is the Xcode error I get when it crashes:
: ImageIO: CGImageReadCreateDataWithMappedFile  'open' failed '/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/782E98C3-0452-43EF-BF4D-401773D5FDCD/WildNoizesLite.app/Duck1_1.png'
             error = 24 (Too many open files)

Backtrace:
* thread #1: tid = 0x301c4, 0x00000001944ab270 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 8, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x00000001944ab270 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 8
    frame #1: 0x0000000194549170 libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill + 112
    frame #2: 0x0000000194422b18 libsystem_c.dylib`abort + 112
    frame #3: 0x00000001934b5418 libc++abi.dylib`abort_message + 116
    frame #4: 0x00000001934d4b8c libc++abi.dylib`default_terminate_handler() + 304
    frame #5: 0x0000000193ce83c0 libobjc.A.dylib`_objc_terminate() + 128
    frame #6: 0x00000001934d1bb4 libc++abi.dylib`std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
    frame #7: 0x00000001934d173c libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_rethrow + 144
    frame #8: 0x0000000193ce8294 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_rethrow + 44
    frame #9: 0x0000000181ef5384 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
    frame #10: 0x000000018b94b6fc GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 168
    frame #11: 0x0000000186af2f40 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1488
  * frame #12: 0x0000000100174fa0 Wild Noizes`main(argc=1, argv=0x000000016fd6f9d8) + 124 at main.m:16
    frame #13: 0x0000000194392a08 libdyld.dylib`start + 4

Comment: "My code below creates a Texture from an image name from file lookups in a plist like (Duck1_1,Duck1_2,Duck1_3,etc) it loops through them then adds them to a mutable array." I'm assuming you are doing this only once correct? You only need to load the textures one time and you can just reuse them. If you are not doing this, and the code you posted above runs constantly then it is horrible inefficient and could be leading to the crash due to reading way too often.

Comment: It can be passed 54 different animations to this function.  A scene is called on button press, plays the animation then removes the animation.  When they hit other buttons then different animations play.